# Send email of new items added to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, send-email

I have a sharepoint list at work, items in the list are generated based on certain company events that are stored in our access database. When a new event is added to the database that event joins the sharepoint list.

This list is updated hourly, based on an access query from an access database (i tbink). The column values for each item also update in this hourly refresh when certain tables have data input in the access database that are connected to this event mentioned in the paragraph above.

I am trying to create a flow that will send an email notification with all the new items added at that hourly run into one html Formatted table.

Currently I have only been able to
Create a flow that sends the new item in a table but a separate email per flow rather than multiple new items in one table and email.

The reason I need to collect all the items in one table is the fact there can be multiple new items joining the sharepoint list every hour the automatic hourly update is ran. Which can result in multiple emails at once.

I’m using the “when a new item is created” action as a trigger to start my flow. Is there any thoughts about a better way of structuring this so that the new items are collected into a single notification?
Would it be better to try and use a get item action ran at intervals to retrieve the new items that were created in the last X time, then try to apply a condition that if they were created in the last X amount of time, my table and email are generated, if no it is blanked? The only issue here is I’m not sure how to apply some sort of filter query to the get items action that would look for new items created in the last hour? Is such a thing possible? I’m not sure my sharepoint list has a column for item created date/time..

Thanks in advance for any sort of help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need Power Automate, unless you want to customize your email message.
If you set an "alert" on the list you will get email notifications about new items, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the job in Power Automate according to your requirement like after every 1 hour and then when you get the items in the power automate flow you can apply filter query like this and based on that you can write your logic to create the html table and put the data into it.
[image]